# How to do active active HA node setup in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

New to postgres and we need to setup active-active HA for postgresql cluster. 
Posgresql documentation has active passive natively supported. Has anyone implemented HA using any tools?

DB is expected to execute huge read write transactions per sec and should be scalable.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the DB you are about to create?

Comment: You can only do active/passive with "off-the-shelve" Postgres. Why do you think you need active/active for  HA? What do you consider "huge"? How many transactions per second do you expect? If you are really, really sure you need it, you can look into Postgres-XL

Comment: expected throughput around 150,000 transactions per second and we are looking at postgres 9.6 version

Answer (score 0):

have a look over https://github.com/zalando/patroni
as one option. There are more, depends on your specific requirements.